# JBL wireless earbuds don't play sound, despite connecting fine

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04

I got a pair of JBL Tune 130NC TWS wireless earbuds. When I pair them through the gnome control center, they show as "connected;" however, the only sound I can get through it is the unicode character \x07 ("bell") that my computer sends when I do something to trigger it (e.g. pressing backspace in the terminal when no characters are present). JBL support suggested I update bluetooth drivers; however, there aren't any driver updates visible under "additional drivers" in Software & Updates. How can I make these earbuds play music?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe installing `pavucontrol` tool can help you.

```
apt install pavucontrol
```

From the GUI in the **Output Devices** tab, check Port dropdown menu. Select the audio device if it appears.

Comment: This seems to have helped! I'm able to play sound, but not high quality.